# Forward user request nodejs with all parameters of the initial request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request

I want to redirect the user request, to call another service:

1. when user reach localhost:8080/test with all the parameters (headers and body) then call the http://localhost:3000/api/user/isAuthenticated api
2. handle the response from that api. 
   For headers, the code below works well but I cannot get it works for body parameters, I use the bodyParse and in /test function I have the whole body of the initial request localhost:8080/test

   ```
    app.all('/test', function (req, res) {

               //req.body all parameters set for the initial request localhost:8080/test

               var options = {
               url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/user/isAuthenticated',
               method: req.method,
               headers: req.headers,
               form: {
                   body:JSON.stringify(req.body)
               }
           };

           request.post(options, function (err, httpResponse, body) {

               //body undefinded if i use form: {    body:JSON.stringify(req.body) } 
               //The body is passed i have something like {"body":"{\"email\":\" ...  when i do req.body in the api controller but not the right format and with the key body so i need to do something like req.body.body in the api controller 

               //but work if i do not pass the body and delete form: { body:JSON.stringify(req.body)  }  i have the response of my api in the body variable below
               console.log("CONSTOLE " + body)

               if (body["authenticated"] == true) {
                   return res.json(body)
               } else {
                   return res.json(body)
               }
           });
       });
   ```

So is there a way to pass all the parameters of the request to call another api directly.

Comment: Did you try just `form : req.body` ?

Comment: When I do that the request is not forwarded nothing happen request do not give any response. It works if i remove form : req.body or use form: { body:JSON.stringify(req.body) }

Comment: Sorry i did body : JSON.stringify(req.body).  When i do  req.body it doesn't work i have the error [1]     throw new TypeError('first argument must be a string or Buffer');
So i tried  body : JSON.stringify(req.body) and the request is not forwarded nothing happen request do not give any response

Comment: @adeneo finally req.body worked. 
I have a strange behavior, if i remove req: req.headers it worked when i pass the body but i cannot pass the body and the whole header at the same time.

Comment: @adeneo you can post your answer I will accept it.